# Trying to access telerik RadEditor controls in master page's code behind as follows...its giving some error

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, telerik

```
foreach (Control control in ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls)

 { 
         if(typeof(Control).Equals(Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor))


         {

             label1.Visible = true; label1.Text = "dhchk";
          // control.CssFiles.Add("~/styles/myStyle.css"); 
         } 

}
```

Error;-

'Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Also, is this the correct way to add CSS class to radEditor controls ??

```
control.CssFiles.Add("~/styles/myStyle.css");
```

I actually wanna add 3-4 customized classes..how to do that?

What am I doing wrong ? Please help...thnx

oh and also I was wondering if I can add some javascript or something in my Master page that will detect the ALL the radEditor controls and set their css classes ? don't know much of Javascript..how can that be made possible? how do I go about that? but first I want css classes to be set in code behind..what's wrong with the code?

[EDIT]

@Geek..I tried calling like this..is it correct?

```
 Control c = new Control();
            DoSomething(c);
```

now its giving this error in the method:-

The type or namespace name 'c' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[EDIT]

I do have this namespace added "using System.Web.UI.WebControls;"  why this error ??

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
  if(typeof(control).Equals(Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor)
```

You have it capitalized, therefore pointing at the .Net Control object, not your control object.

You also need to recursively iterate through the controls in your ContentPlaceHolder.  you could have other objects that have controls in them, but your code will never find them.

```
protected void DoSomething(Control control)(
{

    foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
    { 
        if(typeof(c).Equals(Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor))
        {
           Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor rad = c as Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor;
           rad.CssClass = "MyStyle";
              label1.Visible = true; label1.Text = "dhchk";
           // control.CssFiles.Add("~/styles/myStyle.css"); 
        }
        else
        {
              DoSomething(c);
        }

    }

}
```

So we've found the RadEditor controls now, and assigned them the MyStyle class.  Style them accordingly with css now.

Comment: how do I call this method in my page load event? what arguments do I need to pass ..like if I have many radEditor controls on my page...is this method going to set css classes of ALL the editors on my content page..I think I need to use this "rad.CssClasses.Add("~/Styles.myStyle.css");"  coz there's not just one class that I need to add..they are 4 in no.

Comment: Do I need to pass Editor's ID when calling that method ? but there are many radEditor controls on my content page

Comment: that method's not working right..implemented like u said..plz help with this..thnx  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084849/accessing-radeditor-control-from-master-pages-code-behind-its-not-finding-any