# Accessing RadEditor control from master page's code behind...its not finding any radEditor control when it is there..whats wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, telerik

Its not executing statements in if block in my method

Master Page:-

page load event:-

```
Control c = new Control();
DoSomething(c);
```

My method:-

```
 protected void DoSomething(Control control)(
        {

            foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
            { 
                if(typeof(c).Equals(Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor))
                {
                   Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor rad = c as Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor;

                   label1.Visible = true; label1.Text = "dhchk";
                   rad.CssFiles.Add("~/styles/myStyle.css"); 
                   rad.CssFiles.Add("~/styles/myStyle2.css");
                   rad.CssFiles.Add("~/styles/myStyle3.css");
                }            
                else
                {
                      DoSomething(c);
                }

            }

        }
```

my content page:-

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

    <telerik:RadEditor ID="Editor1" EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="false"  EnableEmbeddedSkins=false runat="server">
    </telerik:RadEditor>

<telerik:RadEditor ID="Editor2" EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="false"  EnableEmbeddedSkins=false runat="server">

    </telerik:RadEditor>
```

[EDIT] **ok when debugging..I rt clicked "c" and then Quick watch...it says "The name 'c' does not exist in the current context" (?!?!)  how so ?**

Comment: I don't understand why you're adding a .css file to an object. You need to add the name of a class to the object.  IN your master Page, make a reference to the .css one time!  I think you need to fix how you're styling the control.  I will make you a sample and post the code in a few hours.  This is all crazy and really easy.  Please post me your current MasterPage and a Page that inherits it so I can see more of what you're doing.

Comment: Also, can you post somewhere on the internet, a page that renders one of your RadControls they way you what it styled (with non-sensitive data of course) ... I'll fix your styling approach, too, if you're interested in going the direction I've suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the Master page renders first so you won't have access from the master page to any of the content page controls. You can achive this using events and passing the control from the content to the master

udpate:
Again - Accessing user controls from the master page is flaw in the whole master->content design. the closest thing I can imagine is adding static function

```
public static void AddDesign(RadEditor obj)
{
...
}
```

and then call the function form the Page_Load  of the user control

```
MASTER_PAGE_CLASS_NAME.AddDesign(RadEditor1);
```

Comment: Could you please give an example or something ? may be some link like how it can be done..would be really helpful..thnx

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure, you can access controls in page like this.

At first: that editor should be probably in some Panel (or some other container), so i should look like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadEditor ID="Editor1" EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="false" EnableEmbeddedSkins=false runat="server" />
    <telerik:RadEditor ID="Editor2" EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="false" EnableEmbeddedSkins=false runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Then try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Controls c in pnl1.Controls)
    {
         if (c is Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor)
         {
              // do you stuff ...
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change things around and call your MasterPage method from the content control.

In your masterpage add the method:

```
public void DoSomething(Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor rad)
{
    label1.Visible = true; label1.Text = "dhchk";
    rad.CssFiles.Add("~/styles/myStyle.css"); 
    rad.CssFiles.Add("~/styles/myStyle2.css");
    rad.CssFiles.Add("~/styles/myStyle3.css");         
}
```

Call the function from an appropriate event in your page/content control. eg Page.Load, Editor1.Load etc

```
Master.DoSomething(Editor1);
```

## Update

From the masterpage, you should search for child controls in the Content controls

```
ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("Editor1");
```

or you could try something like:

```
foreach (Control c in ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls)
{ 
     if(typeof(c).Equals(Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor))
     {
         Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor rad = c as Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor;

         label1.Visible = true; label1.Text = "dhchk";
         rad.CssFiles.Add("~/styles/myStyle.css"); 
         rad.CssFiles.Add("~/styles/myStyle2.css");
         rad.CssFiles.Add("~/styles/myStyle3.css");
      }            
      else
      {
         DoSomething(c);
      }

 }
```

Comment: actually I don't wanna change anything in my content page...just want to access Content page's editor controls in my master page and css to them..won't ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl method help ?? not sure how to implement that...need an idea

Comment: @Serenity - updated my answer to show how to find the child controls in from the masterpage

Answer (score 0):

The load and render events of the master page are fired after those of the content page (as said [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1191194.aspx)). Hence the controls in the content page should be available by the time these two events are fired?

Comment: oh so I need to call that DoSomething() method in master page's pre_init() event ...right ?